# NSURLSession at https (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=310)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I got a Error Message When I use `NSURLSession` to connect a web Service with a https connection (Xcode 7.1)

the error message is following~

> Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=310 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 310.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7fcaf4807260 {_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2096,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}

But My Code is worked well with "http connection".

I use Safari to connect the web Service and Safari give me a alert like "the Certificate is invalid".

Is my problem (`kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=310`....) come from the error SSL Certificate?

and any idea to solve the Problem?

I have set the `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
```

But no working~~~~

thanks in advance~

Comment: hello @Wain , I don't search the similar answer, can you give me a link to check the question is the same?

Comment: By default self signed certificates can't be verified, so you need to deal with that. Either trust the certificate on the device or add code to trust the certificate.